# How to assign a vector of atomic types?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdvector, stdatomic

How can I assign the members of a vector with an atomic type?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<atomic<bool>> myvector;
    int N=8;
    myvector.assign(N,false);
    cout<<"done!"<<endl;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/lchfOvqyL3YKNivk

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:11:28: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::atomic<bool> >::assign(int&, bool)'
   11 |     myvector.assign(N,false);
      |                            ^
```

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <atomic>`. The error (also) mentions `atomic<bool>` as *incomplete type*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::atomic` is neither copyable or move constructible, so you might do instead:

```
std::vector<std::atomic<bool>> myvector(8);
for (auto& b : myvector) { std::atomic_init(&b, false); }
```